# How display pdf in new tab using blob

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this method in TypeScript/Angular, that generate my file

```
 imprimir() {

            this.service.emitirAdvertencia({ parametros: [{ name: 'CODIGO', value: 880 }] })
            .subscribe((response) => {
                console.log(response);             
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);                        

                //this not display my pdf document in a new tab.
                window.open(fileURL, '_blank');

                //this display my document pdf, but in current tab
                window.location.href = fileURL; 
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

This is my service

```
emitirAdvertencia(parametros: Object): any {
        parametros['dbenv'] = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getDbenv();
        parametros['usuario'] = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getUser().codigoUsuario;
        parametros['nome_relatorio'] = 'RelAdvertenciaDB';
        var httpOptions = {

            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': this.localStorage.get('token'),
            }),
            responseType: 'blob' as 'blob',
        };
        return this.http.get(ApplicationContext.URL + '/adiantamento/gerar-relatorio/', httpOptions)
            .map((res) => {
                var report = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                return report;
            });
```

Like a commented in code, when i try open in a new tab, not works, only works if i open in current tab

How open this blob pdf file in new tab ?

Comment: This is defined by the users browser, see this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: The problem is Adblock, has blocked the new tab, after disabling Adblock, it works. Thanks, your comment led me to a solution

Answer (score 17):

I could make it works like this:

```js
var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
let tab = window.open();
tab.location.href = fileURL;
```

Comment: even simpler : `window.open(fileURL);`

Comment: While this solution works, `window.open(fileURL);` gest blocked by the popup blocker. Is there a way to open a new tab without being blocked?

Comment: this is great. How do I set default filename?

Comment: @IsmailS Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller Not yet

Answer (score 10):

> To open file in new Tab, you need to create anchor Element in
> Typescript and add your file url in href attribute of this element.

In my example service response is as `data._body` for file blob, you can arrange it as your output response from your service.

```
var newTab = true;
var inputData = { parametros: [{ name: 'CODIGO', value: 880 }] };

this.service.emitirAdvertencia(inputData).subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
       var contentType = data.headers._headers.get('content-type')[0];
       var blob = new Blob([data._body], { type: contentType });
       var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, { oneTimeOnly: true });
    
       //window.open(url, '_blank', '');
       var anchor = document.createElement('a');
       anchor.href = url;
       if (newTab) {
           anchor.target = '_blank';
       }
       anchor.click();
   },
   error => {
       //TODO
   },
   () => { 
      //TODO 
   }
);
```

Comment: actually do not need to create an anchor element, it just works by creating a new tab through window.open, what was preventing it from opening a tab in chrome was AdBlock

Comment: I could make it works like this `var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                let tab = window.open();
                tab.location.href = fileURL;`

Comment: One doubth, What is property `{ oneTimeOnly: true }` ?

Comment: Solved my problem using React JS + Chrome on android phone and desktop too.