# Routing issue: Angular keeps on redirecting to home page on loading new tab

Tags: angular

I am having a link which I tries to open in a new tab in angular. But my routing is always going to home since the route that the link creates will be always unique.
What have I tried.
In component.html file

```
<a (click) = openFile(element)/>
```

In .Ts file

```
    openFile(myFile: any){
          this.myService.getFile.subscribe((res: any) => {
          const file = new Blob([res]); 
          //file = myOutputfile.pdf
         window.open(file);
}
```

So, the above code actually opens a new tab, but then again redirecting to home page.
First the new tab opens with localhost://myOutputfile.pdf, then immediately getting routed to localhost://home.
The entire angular routing module gets called.
How can I solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How display pdf in new tab using blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321675/how-display-pdf-in-new-tab-using-blob)

Comment: can you show demo in stackblitz ?

Comment: @TheHeadRush: It almost solved my issue. Now that redirect to home is not there. I think I am trying to figure it out

Comment: @GaurangDhorda: I will create and will update you. Thanks

Comment: may be wild card routes is redirecting you to home page @shakz

Comment: Yes..Wild card routes is there. That I cannot avoid. Along with that piece of code which maps to home for **, how I can have this new tab working in tandem is what I am trying for.

Comment: Don't map your root component to `**`. That should be used to indicate a client side 404.

Comment: Ok.. Is there a way to open the pdf url. For me, it is opening up a blob in the new tab.

Comment: I was able to figure this out.I have added responsetype as Httpresponse in the angular post method. This resolved the issue.Thanks all